# Modify eureka server port

Tags: service, microservices, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

Is there a way to modify default port(8761) of eureka server ?
And what property we should use in eureka client to point to customized port of eureka server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
server:
  port: 8099

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```